# Identifying peak elevation in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to define a function to identify peaks in elevation data. Peaks are defined as values that are higher than the 8 adjacent values (three above, one on either side, and 3 below).

Importing is not permitted

In the following data: 87 is a peak as it is higher than 54,82,72,49,69,62,71,61

```
data = [ [20, 54, 50, 64, 60, 63, 60, 48, 20, 20],
     [20, 56, 72, 76, 72, 52, 62, 53, 20, 20],
     [20, 52, 62, 81, 67, 48, 67, 52, 23, 20],
     [20, 54, 54, 82, 72, 42, 64, 50, 22, 20],
     [20, 53, 49, 87, 69, 47, 48, 49, 21, 20],
     [20, 20, 62, 71, 61, 36, 28, 31, 22, 20],
     [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 22, 21, 28, 24, 20],
     [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
     [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
     [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
   ]
```

I've got an idea of how to do it, but not really sure how to write the code.

```
def peaks(list1):
    for item in list1:
        # if item > (item[row][column-1] and item[row][column+1] and item[row-1][column-1] and \
        # item[row-1][column] and item[row-1][column+1] and item[row+1][column-1] and item[row+1][column] and item[row+1][column+1]):
```

How do I translate that commented section into proper python code?

Edit: Alright, why isn't this working? the list coords seems to get overwritten and I can't figure out why.

return should be: [(2, 6), (4, 3)]

```
def peaks(list1):
    for row in range(len(list1)):
        for column in range (len(list1[row])):
            if row != 0 and row != len(list1)-1 \
               and column != 0 and column != len(list1[row])-1:
                coords = []
                if max(list1[row-1][column-1:column+2] + \
                       [list1[row][column-1]] + [list1[row][column+1]] + \
                       list1[row+1][column-1:column+2]) < list1[row][column]:
                    coords.append((row, column))
                return coords
```

Comment: look at the [gradient](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html); each surrounding point's vector will point towards your peak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution. I'm not considering values in the borders because you explicitely said that a maximum should be bigger than the "eight" neighbours.

```
for idxR in range(len(data)):
    for idxC in range(len(data[idxR])):
        if idxR != 0 and idxR != len(data)-1 \
        and idxC != 0 and idxC != len(data[idxR])-1:
        if max(data[idxR-1][idxC-1:idxC+2] + 
               [data[idxR][idxC-1]] + [data[idxR][idxC+1]] + \
               data[idxR+1][idxC-1:idxC+2]) < data[idxR][idxC]:
            print '%d is a maximum' % data[idxR][idxC]
```

OK. This is the new version considering your comment where you say that you would like to have the coordinates. The problem with your version is that you reset the value of *coords* inside the loop and do a return before looping through all the elements. *coords* should be defined at the very beginning and returned at the very end.

```
def peaks(list1):
    coords = []
        for row in range(len(list1)):
            for column in range (len(list1[row])):
                if row != 0 and row != len(list1)-1 \
                and column != 0 and column != len(list1[row])-1:
                    if max(list1[row-1][column-1:column+2] + \
                    [list1[row][column-1]] + [list1[row][column+1]] + \
                    list1[row+1][column-1:column+2]) < list1[row][column]:
                        coords.append((row, column))
        return coords
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to save the coordinates of the peaks to a list and it doesn't seem to be working. See the edited question.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I was overwriting the list as it was in the loop. Thanks

Comment: Javier, thanks for the example, but its very difficult to read. I tried something more Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some Python specific idioms and try to make this code more readable. Let's divide the problem as follows:

1. Given a matrix, return all the core (non-border) indexes;
2. Given a coordinate inside the matrix core, return a list containing it's neighbors coordinates;
3. Given a pair or coordinates and a matrix, check it it's a peak.

The first step can be implemented as follows:

```
def core_indexes(matrix):
    row = matrix[0]

    lines = len(matrix)
    columns = len(row)

    for i in range(1, lines - 1):
        for j in range(1, columns - 1):
            yield i, j
```

Notice that this method doesn't have a return value, it **yields** instead. A function or method that yields is the Pythonic form of writing a generator, that is, a special function that returns the next term of a series each time it's called.

The second step is even simpler, let's use the same trick.

```
def neighbor_indexes(i, j):
    for r in range(i - 1, i + 2):
        for c in range(j - 1, j + 2):
            if (i, j) != (r, c):
                yield r, c
```

The next thing (3rd step) we should do is check if a given position represents a peak. A given value is a peak if, and only if, it's greater than it's maximum neighbor. Let's write that:

```
def is_peak(i, j, matrix):
    max_neighbor = max([matrix[i][j] for i, j in neighbor_indexes(i, j)])
    return matrix[i][j] > max_neighbor
```

Notice the statement below:

```
[matrix[i][j] for i, j in neighbor_indexes(i, j)]
```

It's called a list comprehension. It's translate as "build a list of matrix[i,j] foreach i, j pair returned by the neighbor_indexes function". Quite Pythonic.

Now, it's time to use these functions to scan the matrix. One could do the following:

```
for i, j in core_indexes(data):
    if is_peak(i, j, data):
        print("%d at [%d, %d] is a peak" % (data[i][j], i, j))
```

It will print:

```
67 at [2, 6] is a peak
87 at [4, 3] is a peak
```

Note that our indexes are zero based.

Answer (score 1):

Since this looks like homework, I will give two hints instead of providing a full solution:

1. Write two nested loops, one for rows and one for columns (thinking carefully about what the loop bounds should be).
2. To check that `a` is greater than both `b` and `c`, write `a > b and a > c`.

Comment: Can you expand on 1) a bit?